# Delphi - TListview Artifacts

Tags: delphi, listview

I've had some visual problems with my `Tlistview`.

When my mouse moves by any item from the `listview`, it turns the item invisible! But if I click on it, even if I can't see it, it shows up again.

Here is the screnshot :

[image: Description]

Also, there is a question like this one already, and the final answer was to turning `Doublebuffered to true`. That Didn't worked for me.

1. Tryed to turn on `Doublebuffered` on Delphi compiller - Still the same ;
2. With a `Ttimer`, always setting `doublebuffered` to true - the only problem of that, was  the `Vertical Scrolls` somehow stops at 1/3 of it's range..weird thing ;
3. Turning On `Doublebuffered` and turning off `FullRepaint` ,on the `panels` containing the `Listview`, but still nothing ;

Can someone give me a little help?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to use `DoubleBuffered`. Try and forget about it. Instead you should try to identify the problem.

Comment: i don't know how should i identify the problem, so i use the only tools i know :)

Comment: Just give us something that allows us to reproduce the fault and then ask us to work it out.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? It 'a VCL application? by the appearance of scrollbar seems to be a FireMonkey HD Application

Comment: Delphi XE2 - VCL application - Alphaskins is the secret :)

Comment: Take Alphaskins out then. I cannot believe you didn't mention that! Anyway, without a way for us to repro, this is a non question.